# Can't click AdMob ads

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Okay, I have been wondering why I don't get money any more for ads, and then I realized that I cannot click my ads when I.. click them. Here is my main.xml.

Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pattern_carbon_fiber_dark">

<com.google.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="***************"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentTop="false">
</com.google.ads.AdView>

<ScrollView 
  android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" 
    android:padding="4dp">

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Silent Mode" 
    android:id="@+id/silent_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <ToggleButton 
    android:textOff="OFF" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textOn="ON" 
    android:id="@+id/silentbutton" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Silent Mode">
  </ToggleButton>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/vibrate" 
    android:id="@+id/vibrate_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/vibratebutton" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="ToggleButton">
  </ToggleButton>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Wifi " 
    android:id="@+id/wifi_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/wifibutton" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="ToggleButton">
  </ToggleButton>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/gps" 
    android:id="@+id/gps_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <Button 
    android:id="@+id/gps" 
    android:text="@string/gpsbutton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </Button>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/bluetooth" 
    android:id="@+id/bluetooth_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/bluetooth" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="ToggleButton">
  </ToggleButton>

  <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/brightness" 
    android:id="@+id/screenbrightness_textview" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </TextView>

  <SeekBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:max="255" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/SbBar">
  </SeekBar>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you change out the ad for a button are you able to click it?  This would be a good way to determine if the problem is with the XML Formatting, or the ad code itself.

Comment: Is there an isClickable attribute you can set? Although I would think by default the Ad would be clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change out the ad for a button are you able to click it? This would be a good way to determine if the problem is with the XML Formatting, or the ad code itself.  I don't see anything that is sticking out in the XML that would cause it to not be clickable.

I would suggest either:

1. Try the button suggestion
2. Check the AdMob ad code again to verify you have everything correct.
3. Try recompiling the application to see if there was maybe some sort of bug during that process.

-Also, did you recently make any XML changes around the date you noticed that the money stopped coming in?

Comment: Yes I did make changes, also I am working on the button test now. Sorry for late response.

Comment: What were the changes your made if you can recall? Please leme know results of button test when complete

Comment: The button worked...but, any code to make it like really good, like the ads on angry birds or something that like swipe around to the new ad and have blue backgrounds?

Comment: Well it's sound as if the issue may be the code from admob, i would suggest regenerating the code given by admob and see if it will work again with all new code..

Comment: I have never worked with AdMob but I am guessing on the website it generates code to place into your application so it can tell when someone clicks on it, and also probably gives you the XML to place into your application?

Comment: @CiehanskiApps let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2301/discussion-between-rob-and-ciehanski-apps)

Comment: I will be back on tomorrow if you still need help.. I have downloaded your application and checked it out (sure enough cannot click the ads) however if you need me to assist in debugging please just let me know.. I will check back this post tomorrow.

Comment: Hello Rob, I would appreicate any help you could give me!

Comment: Do you have a way for me to contact you?  I tried to contact you through the market or your application but neither seem to have a "Contact the developer." It would be easier if we can get on a chat or email rather than going back and forth in this from day to day.